# Lack of experience with bounty

Tags: support, bounty, etiquette

I don't have much experience with setting bounties.  Here is my question where I set a bounty: [Which wind instruments are a problem with braces?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32493/which-wind-instruments-are-a-problem-with-braces)

What I was looking for was an answer from a person like a band teacher, who knows how to play many different wind instruments, and knows what happens to middle school musicians who get braces.  Well, it took a while, but I was able to get a conference set up with my son's actual band teacher, and the conversation was very helpful.  So in a way, the bounty should go to him.  Am I allowed to check my own answer as "accepted," and award the bounty to my own question?

Which is not to say that I didn't appreciate everyone's contributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the system won't allow you to award a bounty to your own answer.

If you don't manually choose an answer to award your bounty to within 24 hours of it ending, it will be automatically awarded. It goes to the accepted answer, or, if there is none, or it is your own, then half the bounty will be awarded to the highest scoring answer meeting the following conditions:

> The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
>
> The answer must have a score of at least +2
>
> The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter

The definitive source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/233816

Comment: Very helpful.  My hope is that the bounty will be split between my answer (which was actually my son's band teacher's answer) and @AsianSquirrel, but that answer tied with another very good one, so who knows what will happen when the bounty gets automatically awarded.  (I wasn't able to give AsianSquirrel another vote to push that answer over the edge.)

Comment: No problem. If you think AsianSquirrel's answer was the best, you should award the bounty to them however. When I said above that 'half the bounty was awarded' - I meant half the rep will be awarded, and the other half will disappear. None will ever be applied to your own answer - the other half will just be lost if you don't chose an answer. =)

Comment: @aparente001 Why aren't you just manually giving the bounty to AsianSquirrel if you think that's the best answer?

Comment: @JCPedroza, Sorry I wasn't clear.  I thought my son's band teacher's answer, which I wrote up for him, was the best, most useful answer.  AsianSquirrel's was good too, though.